# Elementos de uma tabela PHP aparecem repetidos e outros não aparecem

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, moodle

Estou montando uma página para exibir os cursos cadastrados dentro do Moodle. Para tanto, estou fazendo testes locais, onde cadastrei 4 disciplinas e 5 usuários. A intenção é exibir essas 4 quatro disciplinas com os nomes do(s) respectivo(s) professor(es) abaixo.

Entretanto, em vez de aparecer as 4 disciplinas, aparecem 5 resultados com algumas anomalias, a saber:

- A disciplinas com mais de 1 professor (3, no caso) aparece repetida - cada um com o nome de professor diferente. A ideia é aparecer apenas uma div para essa disciplina e o nome dos 3 professores aparecerem lado a lado.
- A disciplina sem professor cadastrado não aparece.
- A única normalidade é que as duas (2) disciplinas com 1 professor cada aparecem normalmente, como esperado.

Como no Moodle, o `roleid` para professor deve ser `3`, e o nível de contexto para cursos deve ser `50`, estou usando o seguinte código:

```html
            <!-- Conteúdo das abas: graduação -->
            <div id="cursos" class="tabcontent">
                <?php 
                $sq1 = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT mdl_course.id AS iddocurso, mdl_course.fullname AS nomedocurso, mdl_context.instanceid, mdl_context.contextlevel, mdl_context.id, mdl_user.id, mdl_user.firstname AS nomedoprofessor, mdl_user.lastname AS sobrenomedoprofessor, mdl_role_assignments.roleid, mdl_role_assignments.contextid, mdl_role_assignments.userid, mdl_role_assignments.roleid

                FROM mdl_course 
                INNER JOIN mdl_context 
                      ON mdl_course.id=mdl_context.instanceid 
                INNER JOIN mdl_role_assignments 
                      ON mdl_context.id=mdl_role_assignments.contextid 
                INNER JOIN mdl_user 
                      ON mdl_user.id=mdl_role_assignments.userid 

                WHERE mdl_role_assignments.roleid = '3' AND mdl_context.contextlevel = '50'") 
                
                or die(
                mysqli_error($conexao)
                );
                
                while($aux = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sq1)) { 
                echo '<a href="meusite.php?id='.$aux["iddocurso"].'" target="_blank">';
                echo '<div class="grid__item large--three-tenths medium--five-tenths">';
                echo '<img src="imagens/imagem.jpg" alt="'.utf8_encode($aux["nomedocurso"]).'" title="'.utf8_encode($aux["nomedocurso"]).'">';
                echo '<p class="h6">'.utf8_encode($aux["nomedocurso"]).'</p>';
                echo '<p class="professor"> Professor: '.utf8_encode($aux["nomedoprofessor"]).' '.utf8_encode($aux["sobrenomedoprofessor"]).'</p>';
                echo '<span>Acessar</span>';
                echo '</div>';
                echo '</a>';                
            }
        
                ?>
            </div>
```

Detalhe na imagem: *Tutoria de Matemática* aparece 3 vezes (porque tem 3 professores); *História* não aparece porque não tem professor; *Psicologia* e *Geometria Analítica* estão corretas.

Cada curso tem um ID. Desconfio que tenho que trabalhar com esse ID para exibir os 4 cursos com seus respectivos professores corretamente, mas não sei como proceder nesse caso. Alguma ideia a respeito, amigos?

Grato!

[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá...
O problema está na consulta SQL. Você está pedindo ao banco de dados apenas os cursos com professores cadastrados (através do **INNER JOIN**), para que venham todos (mesmo sem professores), utilize o **LEFT JOIN**.
Sobre a duplicação, utilize o **DISTINCT**, mas lembre-se ele olha os campos retornados e retira as linhas onde todos são diferentes, então talvez você precise retirar alguma coluna da consulta.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    mdl_course.id AS iddocurso,
    mdl_course.fullname AS nomedocurso,
    mdl_context.instanceid,
    mdl_context.contextlevel,
    mdl_context.id,
    mdl_user.id,
    mdl_user.firstname AS nomedoprofessor,
    mdl_user.lastname AS sobrenomedoprofessor,
    -- provavelmente as duplicações ocorrem nos campos abaixo
    mdl_role_assignments.roleid, 
    mdl_role_assignments.contextid,
    mdl_role_assignments.userid,
    mdl_role_assignments.roleid
    FROM
        mdl_course 
        INNER JOIN mdl_context ON mdl_course.id=mdl_context.instanceid 
        LEFT JOIN mdl_role_assignments ON mdl_context.id=mdl_role_assignments.contextid 
        LEFT JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_user.id=mdl_role_assignments.userid 
    WHERE
        mdl_role_assignments.roleid = '3' AND mdl_context.contextlevel = '50'"
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, Marcos! Não conhecia o SELECT DISTINCT! Obrigado pela dica, mas ainda não funciona. Basicamente, ele só está filtrando os cursos onde o mdl_role_assignments.roleid = '3', e é aqui que está, porque nem todo curso terá um professor. =\ Mas valeu pela dica, cara!

Comment: Marcos, acabei de resolver o problema, só que com outra estrutura! E, mais uma vez, obrigado pelas dicas, cara!

Comment: Opa... que bom que conseguiu...qualquer coisa, entre em contato.

Comment: Pode deixar! Muito obrigado, Marcos!

Comment: Disponha... Se puder aceitar marcar a resposta como aceita, agradeço